# Why do I get a 404 when dynamically loading a file that does exist?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, javascript-import

In fact I get three 404s trying to load the same file, but the one I'm interested in occurs here, in my `index.html`:

```
<script>
    System.import('app/main').catch(function (err) { console.error("IMPORT_ERR: " + err); });
</script>
```

The error logged is:

```
IMPORT_ERR: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:57971/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:57971/js/zone.js:647:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:57971/js/zone.js:236:37)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:57971/js/zone.js:136:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:57971/js/zone.js:304:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:57971/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:57971/app/main.js
```

Yet the file in question definitely exists:

```
PS C:\Dev\Angular2\Projects\Introduction\Code\src> ls TourOfHeroes2\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\bundles

    Directory: C:\Dev\Angular2\Projects\Introduction\Code\src\TourOfHeroes2\node_modules\@angular\platform-brow
    ser-dynamic\bundles

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                          
-a----       2016/09/25   8:50 AM           4631 platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js                       
-a----       2016/09/25   8:50 AM           8749 platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js                               
-a----       2016/09/25   8:50 AM           4703 platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js
```

The folder `TourOfHeroes2` is the root of the web app.

Comment: where is the index file? is it located in C:\Dev\Angular2\Projects\Introduction\Code\src\TourOfHeroes2\?

Comment: @AminJafari In TourOfHeroes/wwwroot, as is the convention in ASP.NET Core. No files outside that folder may be served. But how does that matter? The URL used in absolute, and I should get a Forbidden or something, not a 404. Sorry, I have added the 'Core' tag.

Comment: You sure your node packages are located in wwwroot/node_modules or are they rater located in wwwroot/lib? The common convention is to have a lib folder. Or did you add mappings for the libraries in question? Sounds to me like you do not have the correct entries in System.config's map and/or path section. Can you post it together with your folder structure?

Comment: May we see your Configure method of your Startup class?

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan It's in my own answer below.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking in the same direction. Good you found it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the app wasn't allowing requests to static files in the `node_modules` folder[1]. I made numerous small changes to the app before it worked, which I will amend here later today, but the most important ones were, in `Startup`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    UseCustomFileServer(app, env);
}

private void UseCustomFileServer(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // this will serve up wwwroot
    app.UseFileServer();

    // this will serve up node_modules
    var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "node_modules"));
    var options = new FileServerOptions();
    options.RequestPath = "/node_modules";
    options.StaticFileOptions.FileProvider = provider;
    options.EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true;
    app.UseFileServer(options);
}
```

Due to some, I think, bad design, `UseStaticFiles` can only serve static files from one directory, and we need it for `wwwroot`, so I had to add `UseFileServer` for the `node_modules` file source.

[1] .NET Core web apps don't - by default - allow any static files to be served at all. You have to add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` package to `project.json`, and add these two lines to `Startup.Configure()`, in the correct order:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```